# sitefinity integration with existing mvc application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, sitefinity

I am working on POC to integrate sitefinity web app with our current mvc and I kinda get the feeling that sitefinity has to be the main site and then build to it and not the opposite, has it been done before ? I want to include my original views into the sitefinity resource package as layouts and widgets

Answer (score 1):

Your goal in a total integration is to convert all of your controllers to widgets
This can be done either in the SitefinityWebApp project, or in an external project.

Your views can be embedded into the dll as a resource to eliminate the need to shift around cshtml files in deployments.

Converting the controllers to widgets means, largely, decorating the controllers with appropriate attributes, and removing the layout references from your views.

In addition, if you do *not* already use WebApi to return json or xml content, Make sure you understand the use of StandaloneResponseFilter.

Start with this [guide](https://docs.sitefinity.com/feather-create-widgets) to walk you through creating (or converting) or first controllers: